# python - returning a default value

Tags: python, return-value, default-value

I'm looking to mimic the behavior of built-in functions (like `getattr`) that allow the user to specify a "default" return value.  My initial attempt was to do this

```
def myfunc(foo, default=None):
    # do stuff
    if (default is not None):
        return default
    raise SomeException()
```

The problem is that if the users wants `None` to be their return value, this function would instead raise an exception.  second attempt:

```
def myfunc(foo, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
    if ('default' in kwargs):
        return kwargs['default']
    raise SomeException()
```

This addresses the above issue and allows the user to specify any arbitrary value, but introduces an annoyance in that the user must always specify `default=bar` in their function calls; they can't just provide `bar` at the end.  Likewise, `*args` could be used, but prevents users from using `default=bar` if they prefer that syntax.

Combining `*args` and `**kwargs` provides a workable solution, but it feels like this is going to a lot of effort. It also potentially masks improper function calls (eg `bar = myfunc(foo, baz, default=qux)`)

```
def myfunc(foo, *args, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
    if (len(args) == 1):
        return args[0]
    if ('default' in kwargs):
        return kwargs['default']
    raise SomeException()
```

Is there a simpler solution? (python 3.2 if that matters)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use a sentinel to detect that a default value was not set:

```
sentinel = object()

def func(someparam, default=sentinel):
    if default is not sentinel:
        print("You passed in something else!")
```

This works because an instance of `object()` will always have it's own memory id and thus `is` will only return True if the exact value was left in place. *Any other value* will not register as the same object, including `None`.

You'll see different variants of the above trick in various different python projects. Any of the following sentinels would also work:

```
sentinel = []
sentinel = {}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to stop people passing in sentinel?

Comment: @hayden: of course not, this is python. You generally name it `_sentinel` or similar to flag it as private, but that doesn't stop enterprising souls from breaking everything by importing it anyway. There is no point in doing so, of course.