# Using None as parameter to keyword argument

Tags: python, chaining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [python - returning a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265695/python-returning-a-default-value)

I have a function in a class:

```
def foo(self, value = None):
    if value is None:
        return self.value
    self.value = value
    return self
```

This is a getter and setter combined into one, with the advantage that I can chain functions like this:

```
three = anInstanceOfMyClass.foo(3).bar().foo()
```

The problem appears when I do like this:

```
shouldBeNoneButIsThree = anInstanceOfMyClass.foo(3).foo(None).foo()
```

Here foo thinks that I did not pass an argument.
I can avoid this by:

1. Setting value to some strange object, like a random string
2. Create an object instance in the constructor which value has as default value

Both seem a bit too much work, what is an easier way?

setting value to something

Comment: I like chaining since it can change 300 short lines of code into 100 lines, with same or improved readability.

Comment: Nice move, remove your comment after I wrote an answer..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a sentinel to detect that a default value was not set:

```
sentinel = object()

def foo(self, value=sentinel):
    if value is not sentinel:
        print("You passed in something else!")
```

This works because an instance of `object()` will always have it's own memory id and thus `is` will only return True if the exact value was left in place. *Any other value* will not register as the same object, including `None`.

You'll see different variants of the above trick in various different python projects. Any of the following sentinels would also work:

```
sentinel = []
sentinel = {}
```

Comment: Copying your answer from a duplicate question is [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions).

Answer (score 2):

Using a sentinel object value is fairly common; this is what the library does in [`abcoll.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/_abcoll.py#l454):

```
   __marker = object()

   def pop(self, key, default=__marker):
       ...
       if default is self.__marker:
```

Note that the sentinel object should be defined directly in the class.