# Require one out of two keyword arguments

Tags: python

I have a function which can take keyword arguments and I want to require one of them. Let's say dollar and euro and I want one and only one of them. Right now, I'm doing it like this (exemplification) but I find it quite complex. Is there any other better way?

```
def set_value(country, **kargs):
    
    if len(kargs) == 1:
        if kargs.keys()[0] == 'dollar':
            pass # do something
        elif kargs.keys()[0] == 'euro':
            pass # do something
        else:
            raise ValueError('One keyword argument is required: dollar=x or euro=x')
    else:
        raise ValueError('One keyword argument is required: dollar=x or euro=x')
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use set operations on the [dictionary keys view](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

```
if len(kargs.viewkeys() & {'dollar', 'euro'}) != 1:
    raise ValueError('One keyword argument is required: dollar=x or euro=x')
```

In Python 3, use `kargs.keys()` instead.

Demo of the different outcomes of the set operation:

```
>>> kargs = {'dollar': 1, 'euro': 3, 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> kargs.viewkeys() & {'dollar', 'euro'}
set(['dollar', 'euro'])
>>> del kargs['euro']
>>> kargs.viewkeys() & {'dollar', 'euro'}
set(['dollar'])
>>> del kargs['dollar']
>>> kargs.viewkeys() & {'dollar', 'euro'}
set([])
```

In other words, the `&` set intersection gives you a set of all keys present in *both* sets; both in the dictionary and in your explicit set literal. Only if one and only one of the named keys is present is the length of the intersection going to be 1.

If you do not want to allow any *other* keyword arguments besides `dollar` and `euro`, then you can also use proper subset tests. Using `<` with two sets is only True if the left-hand set is strictly smaller than the right-hand set; it only has *fewer* keys than the other set and no extra keys:

```
if {}.viewkeys() < kargs.viewkeys() < {'dollar', 'euro'}:
    raise ValueError('One keyword argument is required: dollar=x or euro=x')
```

On Python 3, that can be spelled as:

```
if set() < kargs.keys() < {'dollar', 'euro'}:
```

instead.

Demo:

```
>>> kargs = {'dollar': 1, 'euro': 3, 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> {}.viewkeys() < kargs.viewkeys() < {'dollar', 'euro'}
False
>>> del kargs['foo']
>>> {}.viewkeys() < kargs.viewkeys() < {'dollar', 'euro'}
False
>>> del kargs['dollar']
>>> {}.viewkeys() < kargs.viewkeys() < {'dollar', 'euro'}
True
>>> del kargs['euro']
>>> {}.viewkeys() < kargs.viewkeys() < {'dollar', 'euro'}
False
```

Note that now the `'foo'` key is no longer acceptable.

Comment: `set() < kwargs.viewkeys() < {'dollar', 'euro'}` checks that `kwargs.viewkeys()` is a proper non-empty subset, i.e. either `{'euro'}` or `{'dollar'}`.

Comment: @Bakuriu: but that would not allow for *extra* keyword arguments.

Comment: Ah, the OP wants a general solution? I didn't get that from the question. In that case I believe checking the length is the only simple way of doing it.

Comment: This won't detect errors at the call site like `set_value(dolar=5, euro=6)`.  Python normally detects these errors and raises a `TypeException`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: what if the OP *wants* to support extra keyword arguments?

Comment: @Bakuriu: Note that `dict.viewkeys()` cannot be used with sets like that; it has to be the left-hand operand. `{}.viewkeys()` as the 'empty' set works though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I'm talking about misspelled keyword arguments.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Maybe in python2? I checked in python3 and it worked. correctly(using `keys()`). Yes, I just checked: it works on python3, but not on python2.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Yes, I understood that; but accepting arbitrary keyword arguments with a `**kwargs` catch-all would not protect against misspellings, ever.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: My second example *does* throw a `ValueError` when passing in `dolar=5`.

Comment: I love the sets/subsets comparisons. Amazing!

Comment: As a note, `viewkeys()` is only available after python 2.7.

Comment: @DiegoHerranz: It is only available *in* Python 2.7. In Python 3, the `.keys()` method returns a view too.

Answer (score 5):

Let's not use `kargs.keys()[0]`, because that depends on the order of the keys, which is unspecified.  It works *now*, but it's fragile because it will break if you add another keyword argument or if you migrate to Python 3.

Note that you'll have to use a [different sentinel if `None` is a valid value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265695/python-returning-a-default-value).

```
def set_value(country, dollar=None, euro=None):
    if dollar is None and euro is None:
        raise TypeError('Need dollar or euro argument')
    if dollar is not None and euro is not None:
        raise TypeError('Cannot have both dollar and euro argument')
```

In general, I try to stay away from using `**kwargs` unless I'm passing the keyword arguments to another function.  If you use `**kwargs`, then you can call `set_value(dolar=5)` and never notice that you misspelled "dollar".

Also note that the correct exception to raise is `TypeError`.

However, if you anticipate an expanding range of currencies,

```
CURRENCIES = {'euro', 'dollar', 'quatloo', 'zorkmid'}
def set_value(country, **kwargs):
    if len(kwargs) != 1 or not CURRENCIES.issuperset(kwargs.keys()):
        raise TypeError('exactly one supported currency must be specified')
```

I would probably not use separate keyword arguments, however:

```
Value = collections.namedtuple('Value', 'currency amount')
def set_value(country, value):
    ...

set_value(country, Value('USD', Decimal('15.30'))
```

Comment: Because len(kargs) == 1, order does not matter as only one key is present.

Comment: What happens when you add another keyword argument?  What happens when you migrate to Python 3?

Comment: With another keyword argument you get ValueError because one and only one keyword argument is required.

Comment: I'm talking about adding another argument to the function, I'm not talking about adding another argument to the function call.

Comment: If you're talking fragile, this will break if (now or in future) `None` is a meaningful value for either keyword argument. Maybe use a global singleton `object()` for the default value, and `is` checks? Certainly, it's a potential wart if specifying the keyword arg equal to `None` has the same effect as not specifying it at all, but the expected behaviour is expressed in terms of whether it's specified.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes, you're right.  However, that is kind of beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Ok. Now I see what you mean with adding another argument. You're right it would be complex to add another keyword argument.

Comment: Hmm, sounds a bit like future changes that you imagine are very important, whereas future changes that I imagine are outside the scope of the question ;-). Not that it's desperately important, the questioner hopefully can assess this stuff for himself. Worst case, if another keyword argument is added and the code in place doesn't easily allow for that, you rewrite a line or two of code...

Comment: @SteveJessop: I had made some assumptions about coding style, mainly that `None` is an okay sentinel about 99% of the time, whereas I add new arguments to existing functions all the time.  I did edit your comment into the answer.

Comment: Of course, the "correct" answer to this question is entirely subjective, but I prefer this method. If you know all of the possible arguments (and there are only two of them), why would you not want to list them out in the function argument list? Doing anything else makes it harder for users reading the function to determine how it actually works. I really don't want to read the entire source of a function to determine what arguments it accepts.

Comment: After reading the answers, I get the feeling that as @MarkHildreth says, it might have been better not to use keyword arguments. But since I made the question that way, I'll accept Martijn Pieters' answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.pop`:

```
def set_value(country, **kwargs):
    euros = kwargs.pop('euro', None)
    dollars = kwargs.pop('dollar', None)
    if (euros is None is dollars) or (euros is not None is not dollars):
        raise ValueError('One keyword argument is required: dollar=x or euro=x')
    elif euros:
        #do something
    else:
        #do something
```