# How can you use the simple assert statements for a function definition to accept 1 of 2 parameters but not both for keyword arguments?

Tags: python, dictionary, assert, keyword-argument

Hi I am having some difficulty with assert statements use in functions. In a function definition, if you have a keyword argument intaking a dictionary as a parameter, how can you use just **the assert statements** to make sure it only accepts 1 of 2 parameters but not both?

i.e.

expDict = {'a':1,'b':2}

The function can only accept a or b but not both

def test(**kwargs):

Comment: Might be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122988/require-one-out-of-two-keyword-arguments

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Require one out of two keyword arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122988/require-one-out-of-two-keyword-arguments)